# Difference between type and struct

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn Julia and am reading a book that shows the following two code example in a chapter about composite types:

1.

```
type Points
    x::Int64
    y::Int64
    z::Int64
end
```

2.

```
struct Point
    x::Int
    y::Int
    z::Int
end
```

The book however does not explain, when to use `struct` and when to use `type`.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is quite a mess in your sources, since it mixes different meanings from non-compatible epochs in the history of the language.

- [Originally](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.5/manual/types/) (pre 0.7, I think?), composite types were declared with either `type` or `immutable`, where `type` was used for mutable types (there also was `bitstype` for what is now called "primitive types").
- [Now](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/), we have `mutable struct` and `struct` for the sampe purposes (and, consistently with it, `primitive type` and `abstract type`).

So, basically the names have changed so that all ways to define types becomes a bit more consistent, and immutable structs have become the "unmarked" case.

"Mutable" in this context means that you can't *reassign* a field (`p.x = 3`).  It does not imply that the contents of a field cannot be changed, it they happen to be mutable (`something.v[1] = 2` will also work if `something` is an immutable type!).

Comment: "Learning Julia", as available here: epdf.pub/learning-julia.html (page 127)

Comment: Hm... it doesn't look too bad, but version 0.5 it uses is seriously outdated. That, and the lot of packages they show will have changed significantly as well! Remember that Julia is a quite young languages, with things still moving fast.

Comment: Totally true. The thing is that I like to read books and there don't seem to be too many out there. (I wasn't able to find a good and fairly comprehensive introduction book by now)

Comment: Legit. Do you know [these resources](https://julialang.org/learning/) already?

Comment: Yes, I saw them. However, it's hard to figure out, which ones of them to read. I bought two of the listed by now and one of them for example is just downright awful, as it does not explain the "Julian" way of programming (as I would have expected from the title "Think Julia"), but instead explains the basics of the basics of programming to someone who hasn't used a computer before. (Sorry, for ranting. ;) )

Comment: Well, that's annoying.

Comment: I have to say, I think the official docs: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/ are excellent. For someone who has previous programming experience and just wants to learn details of the language, I recommend just reading through the "manual" section of the docs.

Comment: @Georgery - I haven't read most of the resources from that link, but I understand what you are saying about "Think Julia" - it has good "Julian" ways of doing things, but really builds up from the ground floor. I would recommend "Hands-on Design Patterns and Best Practices with Julia" if you are already comfortable with programming basics.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. :) I will order this one then.

Answer (score 2):

As argued by @phipsgabler you are mixing code from different versions of Julia.

On this specific topic you can look also on my "Julia concise tutorial", on the topic of "[Custom Structures](https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/custom-types)".

The same topic, extended, is available in the "[Julia Quick Syntax reference](https://www.julia-book.com/)" book (Apress, 2019) from which I report an except from the unedited source (still full of English errors, but you should get the point..):

### Custom Types

In Chapter 2 "Data Types and Structures" we discussed *built-in* types, including containers. In this chapter we move to explain how to create user-defined types.

#### "type" vs "structure":

Let's be clear about these two terms and what they mean in the Julia language context.

As *type* of an object we mean, as in plain English, the set of characteristics that an object can be described with. For example an object of type *sheet* can be described with its dimensions, weight, colour..

All values in Julia are true objects belonging to a given type (they are individual "instances" of the given type).

Julia types include so called *primitive types* made of just a fixed amount of bits (like all numerical types.. `Int64`, `Float64`, but also `Char`..) and *composite types* or *structures*, where the set of characteristics of the object is described trough multiple fields and a variable number of bits.

Both structures and primitive-type can be user-defined and are hierarchically organised. Structures roughly correspond to what *classes* are known in other languages.

#### Primitive type definition

A user-defined primitive type is defined with the keyword `primitive type` and just its name and the number of bits it requires:

`primitive type [name] [bits] end`

For example:

`primitive type My10KBBuffer 81920 end`

IMPORTANT: A (current) limitation of Julia is that the number of bits must be a multiple of 8 below 8388608.

Optionally a parent type can be specified:

`primitive type [name] <: [supertype] [bits] end`

Note that the internal representation of two user-defined types with the same number of bits is exactly the same. The only thing that would change is their names, but that's an important difference: it's the way that functions are defined to act when given objects of these types are passed as arguments that changes, i.e. it's the usage across the program of named types that distinguish them rather than their implementation.

#### Structure definition

In a similar way of primitive types, to define a structure we use the keyword `mutable struct`, give the structure a name, specify the fields, and close the definition with the `end` keyword:

```
mutable struct MyOwnType
  field1
  field2::String
  field3::Int64
end
```

Note that while you can optionally define each individual field to be of a given type (e.g. field3::Int64) you can't define fields to be subtypes of a given type (e.g. `field3<:Number`). In order to do that you can however use templates in the structure definition:

```
mutable struct MyOwnType{T<:Number}
 field1
 field2::String
 field3::T
end
```

Using templates, the definition of the structure is dynamically created the first time an object whose field3 is of type `T` is constructed.

The type with whom you annotate the individual fields can be either a primitive one (like in the example above) or a reference to an other structure (see later for an example). +

Note also that, differently from other high-level languages (e.g Python), you can't add or remove fields from a structure after you firstly defined it. If you need this functionality use <> instead, but be aware that you will trade-off this flexibility with worse performances.

At the opposite, to gain performances (but again trading up with flexibility), you can omit the `mutable` keyword in front of `struct`.
This will constraint that once an object of that type has been created, its fields can no longer be changed (i.e., structures are immutable by default).

Note that mutable objects -as arrays- remain themselves mutable also in a immutable structure.